# How to pass multiple arguments in CommandArgument in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was working on asp.net GridView control. Now I need to edit some row data. For that I was using this code:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" Text="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="QuickEdit"  OnClick="btnEdit_Click"
  CommandArgument ='<%# ((CheckBox)(((GridViewRow) Container).Cells[4].Controls[0])).Checked %>'/>
```

And the `btnEdit_Click` method is:

```
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender,EventArgs  e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
    switch (btn.CommandName)
    {
        case "QuickEdit":

        EditPanel.Visible = true;
        GridPanel.Visible = false;
        CheckBox cbRequiresState = (CheckBox)EditPanel.FindControl("checkRequiresState");

        if (btn.CommandArgument =="True")
        {
            cbRequiresState.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            cbRequiresState.Checked = false;
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

Now, I need to pass more than one argument as `CommandArgument` to that `btnEdit_Click` method. For that what I need to do?
And please suggest me a good way to utilize those arguments in that method.

Comment: Why not use the GridView `OnRowCommand` event?

Answer (score 5):

here is an example :

in your aspx code :

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnSelect" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/btnSelect.png" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex +";"+Eval("ID") %>' ToolTip="select" CausesValidation="False" /></ItemTemplate>
```

and in your code behind :

```
    string info = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    string[] arg = new string[2];
    char[] splitter = { ';' };
    arg = info.Split(splitter);
```

Comment: I was trying like this:    
    CommandArgument ='<%#Container.DataItemIndex+";"+((Label)(((GridViewRow)Container).Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text+";"+ ((CheckBox)(((GridViewRow) Container).Cells[4].Controls[0])).Checked %>'/>
but some error was there:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a string and separate the values by `;` or another character.

Comment: I was trying like this:    
    CommandArgument ='<%#Container.DataItemIndex+";"+((Label)(((GridViewRow)Container).Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text+";"+ ((CheckBox)(((GridViewRow) Container).Cells[4].Controls[0])).Checked %>'/>
but some error was there:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

Comment: you can't do that ((Label)(((GridViewRow)Container).Cells[1].Cont‌​rols[0])).Text. I think you need to set the command argument in the RowDataBound Event

Answer (score 0):

Because `CommandArgument` is a simple string, concatenate the arguments you want to pass to the event putting some kind of separator among them.

Then in `btnEdit_Click` split the values by separator.

**NOTE:** Chose the sepatator so that it isn't  a character contained in anyone of the parameters passed to the event.

Comment: I was trying like this:    
    CommandArgument ='<%#Container.DataItemIndex+";"+((Label)(((GridViewRow)Container).Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text+";"+ ((CheckBox)(((GridViewRow) Container).Cells[4].Controls[0])).Checked %>'/>
but some error was there:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

Comment: @TamalKantiDey how many columns do you have in your GridViewRow? It seems you are trying to access an out-of-range cell...